# Send http request from TCP client in java to Apache

Tags: java

I am trying to send a http request from a tcp client in java. I want to read the http request message from a text file and send the http request through my tcp client.

Http message

> GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
>   Host:http://localhost/xampp/               (is this correct? I want to send request to my   localhost)
>   From:xyz@something.com
>   Accept:text/html, text/plain
>   User-Agent:Mozilla/3.5.3

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

> Host:http://localhost/xampp/ (is this
>   correct? I want to send request to my
>   localhost)

I believe you should put at host only "localhost" instead of "http://localhost/xampp/".
I believe you should also modify "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" to "GET /xampp/index.html HTTP/1.1"

### Telnet

But I would first do some debugging via telnet, And if successful I would write code

```
telnet localhost 80
```

From [wikipedia.com](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_message)

> Below is a sample conversation
>   between an HTTP client and an HTTP
>   server running on www.example.com,
>   port 80.
>       [edit] Client request
>
> ```
>  GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
>  Host: www.example.com
>
>
> A client request (consisting in this case of the request line and only
> ```
>
> one header) is followed by a blank
>   line, so that the request ends with a
>   double newline, each in the form of a
>   carriage return followed by a line
>   feed. The "Host" header distinguishes
>   between various DNS names sharing a
>   single IP address, allowing name-based
>   virtual hosting. While optional in
>   HTTP/1.0, it is mandatory in HTTP/1.1.
>       [edit] Server response
>
> ```
>  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>  Date: Mon, 23 May 2005 22:38:34 GMT
>  Server: Apache/1.3.3.7 (Unix)  (Red-Hat/Linux)
>  Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Jan 2003 23:11:55 GMT
>  Etag: "3f80f-1b6-3e1cb03b"
>  Accept-Ranges: bytes
>  Content-Length: 438
>  Connection: close
>  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
> ```

Comment: You can write http headers in Telnet? Wow, didn't know that

Comment: @TheLQ yup you can put it in raw mode :)